# Can iframe tags be nested?

Tags: html, iframe

I have a weird situation that I can't find a definitive answer to.

We are working with two sites. Site B is presenting an iframe which is presenting Site A, a simple web application. This works perfectly fine.

We now have Site C. Site C wants to present a page with an iframe that includes Site B. Site C presents Site B, but the web app in Site A no longer works. The web and application logs (for Site A) all show the interaction, but Site C does not show an updated render of Site B.

In other words, Site C includes an iframe with Site B, which includes an iframe with Site A.

Is such nesting allowed?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console when this is tested?  Can you provide a running example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: There are no errors in the browser console. Tailing the nginx logs and the phoenix logs show accesses to the page and all the proper site activity. Unfortunately, I can't post links, as the pages are not set up for public consumption yet.

Comment: *"Unfortunately, I can't post links, as the pages are not set up for public consumption yet."* - Creating an isolated proof-of-concept test would likely be the best approach in this case.  If it demonstrates the problem, it can be observed and diagnosed.  If it doesn't demonstrate the problem (and works as intended) then it answers the question.

Comment: Let me see if I can set this up. my hope was that someone would say that nesting iframes cannot be done. I have several private proofs of concept, but I will see if I can make a public site.